# Actualizar tabla de DB con PHP para mostrar en sitio web

Tags: php, html, web

Estoy realizando un proyecto de la universidad sobre un sitio web manejando HTML, CSS y PHP. Tengo escasos conocimientos de este tema pero aca estoy con la siguiente duda.

Tengo que actualizar los datos de una tabla donde la informacion esta almacenada en una bd. Este es mi codigo de como va todo.

1- tengo mi formulario ya creado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- procedi a hacer el pho de modificar, donde realizo la conexion y ejecuto la sentencia para ejecutar el UPDATE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien hasta ahi, cuando ejecuto esto en el servidor local para hacer la pruebva me salta este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon tu codigo como texto, no como foto.

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega tu código como texto

Comment: Los formularios utilizan el name para identificar los valores enviados, tienes 2 inputs con `name = "id"`. Saludos.

Comment: Primero, tenes en el formulario 2 campos con el mismo name, y eso es lo que recibe tu otra pantalla, por lo tanto te recomiendo ponerle al id viejo name="idOld" y al nuevo name ="idNew", después a la hora de recibirlos simplemente hace $idOld = $_POST["idOld"]; no es necesario poner eso entre parentesis, avisame si con eso se soluciona.

Comment: Y después a la hora de hacer el UDPATE a la bdd, tendrías que hacer set `id`= '$idNew', `nombre` ='$nombre' WHERE `id` ='$idOld'

Comment: Y una cosa más al action del formulario donde pones la url a la cual tienen que llegar los datos ponelo entre comillas action="modificar.php"

Answer (score 1):

La captura de pantalla del error se observa en la barra de navegación que le estas pasando los parámetros por el método GET, por tal motivo en tu código al invocar POST te genera dicho error pues no existe.

También se observa que estas utilizando 2 valores para la misma variable "id", tienes que diferenciarlo tal vez id1 y id2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor no usemos imágenes para responder salvo que sea absolutamente necesario

Comment: Si ves el código de la imagen (aunque debe cambiarlo a texto), el formulario utiliza el metodo `POST`, no `GET`. Saludos.